# how to call function in .java class from a HTML 5 page on button click in android?

Tags: android, html

I am creating an android app in which, I want to call the function in the .java class from the
Html page on the button click. I'm not sure how to do that as i'm quite new to android. So, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Class and bind JavaScript in a `WebView` to its methods:

`webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyClass(), "my_class");`

from JavaScript you caninvoke that method:

```
my_class.doStuff();
```

See [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to add one class in Android which will act as an Interface bridge between Html an Java. And in Callback method you will handle events from Html.

Add below code at java side to add interface -

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new ClassName,INTERFACE_NAME);
```

From javascript  call

```
INTERFACE_NAME.method()
```

Comment: Please visit link shared by User117, which is from android documentation.

Comment: Where is the link (User117)?